# How To: Eclipe maven project, want maven dependency jars in src as .java files to edit

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import

I'm unfamiliar with Maven and I was wondering if it was possible to edit (some of the) jars in the Maven Dependency file.

Basically, I want to import 3 jars into my src folder, so that the files are available for editing as .java files.

Using right click on my src folder, import and then archive file didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. You have to

1. Fork the 3rd party projects
2. Modify the sources
3. Create the library jars
4. Install the libraries to your repository (better) with new version numbers
5. Reference the new libraries in your project

However, most often it is more sensible not to change the 3rd party projects but to use the "official" hooks of the libraries such as listeners, filters, interceptors or to use an IOC framework such as Spring and replace some implementations if this is possible.

Comment: M2e knows how to resolve artifacts from open projects. This makes the process much easier.

Comment: Nevertheless the project must be forked.

Comment: Not necessarily. Original source jars can be used even when changed if you just want to test things. If you need the changes to be permanent and visible to others it is another matter

Comment: Changing the sources does not automatically create the class files or the jar libraries.

Comment: M2e knows how to resolve artifacts from open projects.